# Java: how to write a wsgi server

Tags: java, wsgi

I'm writing a web server by Java. This server is just to use socket to get the connection from client,   parse the request and call the corresponding handler to handle this request. But I want to make a page using Django. However, I don't know how to run python script when the server get the request, and Django site tell me that it can be used in Apache by wsgi, so I guess I can do it as well, but how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit confusing as to what you are really after. If you want to run Python WSGI applications, including Django on a Java server, then look at Jython and modjy.

http://opensource.xhaus.com/projects/show/modjy

Answer (score 2):

To get a good idea of what is WSGI you can read the official documentation ([PEP-333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/)). But basically WSGI is a big hash table that you pass to your WSGI application.

Since you are writing your server with Java an important part of your project will be to figure out how to call python code from inside your Java code.

But if you avoid writing this Java web server, you can tale a look at other tools that will give give your a better support to run your python WSGI app.

- Apache with mod_wsgi
- [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org) with [wsgid](http://wsgid.com)
- [Nginx](http://nginx.com/) with [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)

Good luck!